# javascript: check a condition for a <td> value in a table depending on its table header

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML page I have a dynamic table which receives data from database. All cells have numeric values. I need to check different condition for different columns whether the value is less than or greater than a particular value and give background color to that cell according to the result. And I don't want to give a id for each td tag . I want to fulfill this with JavaScript. Following is the code that I have implemented.

```
function color() {
    var val = 0; //value to be compared with
    var header = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("th");
    for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
        if (header[j].innerHTML == "NB HC") { //comparing the table header
            var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                if (cells[i].innerHTML > val) {
                    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after this code the result is, the comparison is happening in all columns. I want this to happen in the column with header "NB HC".

My HTML looks like ,

```
<body onload="color()">

<table  id="test">

    <tr>
        <td>B HC</td>
        <td>NB HC</td>
        <td>Support HC</td>
    </tr>

          <core:forEach items="${myCondition}" var="row">
       <tr>


                <td width="60 px" align="center">my Value</td>


               <td width="60 px" align="center">my Value 1</td>


               <td width="60 px" align="center">my Value 2</td>
     </tr>
    </core:forEach>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is always a string.

Comment: But comparing the value is happening successfully and the background color is appearing. But the problem is, its happening in all columns. I don't want to happen that.

Comment: Instead of getting all `td`s in your table, loop through all `tr`s (in your tbody so it won't get the header row) and then get all `td`s in that row and just check the `td` with the same index (`j`) as your header.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by if I change the value to 10 it wont work. Because it did work. @Teemu

Comment: looping through the tr and then moving to the td did not produced the expected output. @christian314159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have find out Index of Colum of Header "NB HC". Then make loop on the records to compare with change back ground color

```
    function color() {
        var val = 0; //value to be compared with
        var ColIndexToCheck=0;
        var header = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("th");
        for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
        if (header[j].innerHTML == "NB HC") 
           ColIndexToCheck=j;
        }

          var trs= document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
                if (trs[i].cells[ColIndexToCheck].innerHTML > val) {
                    trs[i].cells[ColIndexToCheck].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's say you have 3 `<td>` tags like so and you don't want to id them. A nice workaround to this is:

`document.getElementsByTagName('td')[index#]` So the first `<td>` on the entire webpage would be an index of `[0]`. You could put this in a `for` loop and have a variable as the index number, then perhaps add a line after the line above to get the value `.value` or `.nodeValue` or `.innerText` depending on what child node you are trying to compare.

With that said, every iteration of the loop could check `if` the `<td>` is a certain condition and make the necessary changes the way you want. I would provide a more thorough answer, hut I have no idea what your HTML looks like. All in all, I think the Index number after `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]` is what you needed, that way it doesn't return all tags in your problem, just specific ones.